# Cannot read Xml from my Api Gives error Data at the root level is invalid. Line 1, position 1

Tags: c#, xml, xmlreader

Every time I try to pull XML from my database web api (I created) the XMLTextReader.Read() gives an error saying.

> Data at the root level is invalid. Line 1, position 1.

My XmlReader Code is:

```
String URLString = @"https://localhost:44331/api/voter/4220180288473";
XmlTextReader reader = new XmlTextReader(URLString);
reader.MoveToNextAttribute();
while (reader.Read())
{
     // Do some work here on the data.
    Console.WriteLine(reader.Name);
}
Console.ReadLine();
```

My XML [looks like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8TVnK.png):

```xml
<Voter>
  <Name>Zeeshan Mustafa</Name>
  <Password>1234</Password>
  <PlaceID>khil</PlaceID>
  <VotersID>4220180288476</VotersID>
  <casted>false</casted>
</Voter>
```

Comment: I ran your code and it seemed to work fine when I used this url string: https://www.w3schools.com/xml/note.xml

Comment: Make sure you do not have any white characters at the beginning of the data.